# Argument Unpacking while Defining Function in Python

Tags: python, function, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to pass a list into the definition of a function in order to create new variables. The use case here is to run scipy's [curve fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to find optimal parameters of the function. I want this function to be able to take any number of variables dynamically without specifically typing in all the variables I want it to optimize/solve for (b1, rate_1, etc.). Right now I have a list of the variables to include but can't seem to get the function to create them as new parameters in the function definition, which it looks like I need to do.

I'm familiar with using * in a function as seen below, but it seems that is for when the function is already defined and you're calling it. I want to do something similar but in the definition of the function so the function itself recognizes b1, rate_1, etc. as parameters that it can solve for using curve_fit.

My starter code:

```
def get_optimal_adstock_multivariate(x_var_names):
   y = np.array(final_df['Count Of Solutions'])
   # make list of coefficient variables (b1, b2, etc.) and make new variables for each rate (rate_1, rate_2, etc.)
   coef_vars = []
   rates = []
   for i in range(0, len(x_var_names)):
      coef_vars.append("b" + str(i+1))
      rates.append("rate_" + str(i+1))
   coef_vars_rates = coef_vars + rates

   def f(final_df, b0, *coef_vars_rates): # using * to pass b1, rate_1, b2, rate_2, etc. as parameters (unpacking the list)
      # need this function to recognize final_df, b0, b1, rate_1, etc. as variables
```

Comment: See 1.2 [usage of **kwargs](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html). This may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly make the function recognize these variables unfortunately.
You can use keyword arguments with a double-* and address them from the resulting dictionary object:

```
def f(a, b, **kwargs):
    ... kwargs["b0"] ...
```

Posting this in hope that it might help you, though I am aware it's not a full solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with `x_var_names`.

We can define equivalent functions:

```
In [260]: a, b, c = 1,2,3
In [261]: def foo0(x, *args):
     ...:     print(x, args)
     ...: 
In [262]: def foo1(x, a,b,c):
     ...:     print(x, a,b,c)
     ...:
```

and call them a list of variables or the actual variables:

```
In [263]: alist=[a,b,c]
In [264]: foo0(100,*alist)
100 (1, 2, 3)
In [265]: foo1(100,*alist)
100 1 2 3
In [266]: foo0(100,a,b,c)
100 (1, 2, 3)
In [267]: foo1(100,a,b,c)
100 1 2 3
```

Or if I refine the `print` in `foo0` I get the same display in both:

```
In [268]: def foo2(x, *args):
     ...:     print(x, *args)
     ...: 
In [269]: foo2(100,a,b,c)
100 1 2 3
```

Look at `curve_fit`.  It will work with either `foo1` or `foo2` signatures.

```
f(xdata, *params)
```

The number of `params` is determined by `p0`, though it also talks about determining them by introspection.  By that I think it can deduce that `foo1` expects 3 values.

Don't confuse variable names in the global environment with the variables, or tuple of values passed via `curve_fit` to your function.  Local names can also be different.  For example

```
def foo3(x, *args):
    a,b,c = args
    print(x, a,b,c)
```

uses local unpacking, where the `a,b,c` are just convenient ways of referencing the values in the function.